# Purely mechanical question about torques in human body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

Im trying to program an active ragdoll animation system for my game, and ive been stuck on this question for a while.

Lets imagine a body falling backwards as shown on the scheme below. My question is - purely mechanically, what prevents the butt muscle there from providing enough torque to make the body stand upright again? Or to even slow down the fall?

[image]

Im asking cause right now im applying the same constant amount of torque, to make my ragdoll stand upright. And when body starts to fall, this torque acts unnaturally, making it stand under forces that should destabilize it, or slow down the fall, when it actually gets destabilized.

Comment: I trust that you understand that you can't only ask about the effect of that muscle group on the thigh while ignoring it's effect on the torso, so ... what happens to the center of mass when you apply the torque: does it get closer to or father from the supported region (basically the footprint)?

Comment: Yes, I understand that in reality pretty much all the body parts would play some role in what can and cannot happen. I would love to get the explanation for exactly this simplified scheme, and then ill probably will be able to apply it for actual full 3d ragdoll.

Comment: Torque doesn't move the center of mass, force does. For the CM to move over the legs again, an external force is needed.

Comment: @ja72 hm, i see. My terminology was wrong, but the question still stands. Why would this need an external force? Why the force provided from the butt muscle wouldnt be enough?

Comment: The combined center of mass needs to move over the legs and that requires an external force. Its the laws of motion. But you can alternatively move the legs under the center of mass (like cats do).

Comment: @ja72 still not answering the question. I didnt ask about what is required for balance and how to achieve it. Can you please elaborate, what laws of motion exactly prevent it from happening? Just for this simplified sccenario.

Comment: The muscle provides equal and opposite forces between the parts that it connects two. So the net force is zero as far as the motion of the center of mass. But it is more complex than this. Without friction, image the ragdoll in space? Will the CM move? With friction (which is an external force) it is possible to move the CM to upright the doll.

Comment: @ja72 But its not gonna be equal and opposite, if you consider other parts shown on the scheme, right? How will those parts and their velocities/torques affect how much force/torque the muscle will apply to the "spine" and to the "thigh"?

Comment: A muscle, or a motor always applies equal and opposite forces and torques.

Comment: @ja72 okay. But the amount of movement would be different. I'll rephrase again. If we stand upright and rotate the leg backwards, it wouldnt rotate the pelvis/spine. But in the falling situtation, like on the image, it would rotate pelvis/spine more, than it would rotate leg, right? Why?

Comment: In theory, if you contract the muscles fast you could do a backflip and land on your legs. But to gently and slowly upright yourself by flexing muscles it cannot be done because your feet will lose contact. Glue the feet to the ground and then, yes.

Comment: @ja72 .... Can you please re-read the question? You keep telling me obvious things, while completely ignoring my question. I didnt ask "how", i asked "why".

Comment: Is the floor traction zero, limited or infinite? The only external forces applied to the articulated system is contact normal, friction & gravity. This changes the problem at hand.   Also, do you agree that if the doll was floating in space then any muscle contractions _would not_ cause an overall rotation?

Comment: @ja72 limited. How exactly those external forces affect the final rotation in a way that makes the "thigh" rotate more than "torso" when standing upright, but in falling situation makes "torso" rotate more, than the "thigh"? And by "how" i mean mathematically. Can you show me a free-body diagram, with all the forces acting, and calculations, why final rotations depends on those external forces?

Comment: The math is very complex to show it here. There are 6 degrees of in the diagram shown, with one contact constraint and one friction. Even with only two connected bodies the math is complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is *"what prevents the butt muscle there from providing enough torque to make the body stand upright again?"*

The answer is the limited traction from the ground.

[image: pic]

What you are trying to do (if you have a very heavy head) is move the center of mass over the legs, by keeping everything stiff and bending at the hip in the direction shown. The requirement for that to happen is the bodies (3), (2) and (1) above remain still and do not respond to the muscle torque. So you can argue that the forces to keep (3) in equilibrium come from (2) and the forces to keep (2) in equilibrium come from (1). But the forces to keep the foot on the ground (not sliding or lifting) come from the contact normal $N$ and more importantly the friction $F$ and reaction moment $M$ (our feet are flat and not single points for this reason).

The way things are connected creates a large system of equations which in planar form means three equations for each of the 4 bodies. That is 12 equations for the 3 degrees of freedom (joints at (1), (2) and (3)) and 9 constraint forces (forces and torques at each joint).

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \mathbf{F}_1 & = m_1 (\ddot{\mathbf{x}}_1 - \mathbf{g}) + \mathbf{F}_2 \\
 \mathbf{F}_2 & = m_2 (\ddot{\mathbf{x}}_2-\mathbf{g}) + \mathbf{F}_3 \\
 \mathbf{F}_3 & = m_3 (\ddot{\mathbf{x}}_3-\mathbf{g}) + \mathbf{F}_4 \\
 \mathbf{F}_4 & = m_4 (\ddot{\mathbf{x}}_4 -\mathbf{g}) \\
 {\tau}_1 +\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{F}_1 & = \mathrm{I}_1 \ddot{\theta}_1 + {\tau}_2 + \mathbf{n}_1 \times \mathbf{F}_2 \\
 {\tau}_2 + \mathbf{b}_2 \times \mathbf{F}_2 & = \mathrm{I}_2 \ddot{\theta}_2 + {\tau}_3 + \mathbf{n}_2\times \mathbf{F}_3\\
 {\tau}_3+\mathbf{b}_3 \times \mathbf{F}_3 & = \mathrm{I}_3 \ddot{\theta}_3 + {\tau}_4 + \mathbf{n}_4\times \mathbf{F}_4\\
 {\tau}_4+\mathbf{b}_4 \times \mathbf{F}_4 & = \mathrm{I}_4 \ddot{\theta}_4 \\
\end{aligned}$$

and your question being, how does the torque ${\tau}_4$ affect the combined center of mass acceleration

$$ \ddot{\mathbf{x}}_C = \frac{m_1 \ddot{\mathbf{x}}_1 + m_2 \ddot{\mathbf{x}}_2 + m_3 \ddot{\mathbf{x}}_3 + m_4 \ddot{\mathbf{x}}_4}{m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4} $$

I am unable to explain it in simpler terms, other than what makes the parts move to the right is external forces that act to the right, like the friction $F$ I drew above.

YouTube some videos of people getting up or righting themselves while wearing skis and you will notice the technique of stiffening the muscles  while trying to lean forwards. Now you will notice that without poles it is impossible to do so because the skis don't have enough traction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the points of the rag doll as the tendons are like in a human body. This will allow the doll to be restricted only to fall or stand in a certain way. Knees don't bend sideways or backwards. Try rubber bands at different tensions to make it stand naturally.

Comment: Did this help??

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, thats not what the question was about.

Comment: @CustomPhase This might  be better in engineering. I have also revised my answer

Comment: Try standing with out using your arms with your feet together.

Comment: Im sorry, but how is that an answer to my question? I understand that all joints in our bodies have certain limits. That torque on the scheme is within the limits, isnt it? Regarding rubber bands - thats what im trying to emulate essentially. I thought the question was pretty clear, i dont know how to simplify it even further. Also dont see why would it be engineering, when its about mechanics, forces and torques. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: With out the doll being as complex as the human body it cannot without going into robotics. You might be able to use electromagnets to keep it standing. cut the power to sit and with rubber bands to help stand when the power is reapplied.

Comment: ...I dont want to keep it standing, please re-read the question. You are overthinking it.  Thats why i added "purely mechanically". Forget its a human body. Imagine its just a bunch of wooden planks held together by hinge joints (limits similair to human), with rubber bands attached to different parts that can contract on command. If we make the butt rubber band contract, while all other rubber bands stay the same, why wouldnt it be enought to make the whole thing stand straight up, and instead would cause the rotation of the "spine" plank?

Comment: Along with using rubber bands put little electromagnets at the joints with a remote switch. When the switch is activated the joints all come together and stands. The on command part make it complicated.

Comment: Add a string to the side that is not acting right to restrict that turn

Comment: You have any real pictures of it?

Comment: You havent re-read it, have you? Im not making a robot, its a virtual model. Physics-wise, all i can do is apply torques directly to parts of the model. I need to calculate the torque that the rubberband would apply to both connected parts in the similair case. Is it more clear this way?

Comment: You are right let me research more